# How do I stop a defined method from mutating the argument passed to it?

Tags: ruby

I'm picking up the fundamentals of Ruby, and I stumbled upon something I can't figure out. Here's a very simple version of it, just to figure out the concepts involved.

Suppose I define a method like this:

```
def no_mutate(array)
  new_array = array
  new_array.pop
end
```

Now I call the method:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
no_mutate(a)
```

I would expect printing a would now give: [1, 2, 3]
But instead, it gives: [1, 2]

Since I've defined a new variable and pointed it to whatever array I'm passing in, and then modifying the new variable, why is the array I'm passing in also being mutated?  In this example, why does no_mutate mutate 'a'? How would I avoid mutating 'a'?

Comment: Use the `dup` method: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-dup

Comment: You are not modifying the new variable, you are modifying the array. Arrays aren't objects, you can't "modify" them. You can assign to them, or you can dereference them. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all the others have said you will have to create a copy, either using `array.clone` or `array.dup`.
The reason that happens is becuase ruby is both pass by value and pass by reference.

For example:

```
a = 'hello'
b = a

b << ' world'

puts a
#=> "hello word"
```

This happens because `b` is a new variable but it's points to the same memory location as `a`, so when `b` changes in a way that doesn't create a new object in any way (such as using the `<<` operator) `a` will change as well.

That why you have to duplicate or clone it to create a variable that also has it's own copy of the data rather than just a  variable that points to the same copy as the original.

Answer (score 1):

In the method `no_mutate`, `new_array` and `array` both reference to the same `Array` object, that's why modifying `new_arry` would modify the other as well.

You could copy the content instead:

```
def no_mutate(array)
  new_array = array.dup
  new_array.pop
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a reference to the array--you haven't copied anything, and are operating on the original. Just because you set a new variable to the same reference doesn't change that.

You'd need to make a "defensive copy" and operate on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the lack of mutate, use

`new_array = array.clone`

Makes a new copy of the original array and your changes don't propagate to the original array.